# Flutter: unwanted ellipsis in scaffold Actionbar title , Persian word

Tags: android, android-actionbar, flutter, persian, scaffold

I set title of `Actionbar` in Scaffold a Persian word :

```
new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('لغت نامه'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new Icon(Icons.settings)
        ],
      ))
```

but get this: An ellipsis title
[image: title get ellipsis]

I don't have any idea why this is happening. How can I prevent this?

this Persian title has 8 alphabet, if I set the title in English with the same size, no problem occurs, the problem is with Persian alphabet.

**Workaround**
I put 3 space before and after the Persian text: '\u0020\u0020\u0020لغت نامه\u0020\u0020\u0020'

[image: 3 space before and after text]

Comment: Is the language setting on the device also set to Persian?

Comment: no, but it should work even if the device locale not set to persian like in apps written in java

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Text(
          [your_text],
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the width size of scaffold view in xml. It's displaying only half of the text which you have given in the program.

Comment: xml? there is no xml in a flutter project